# React import modal not working (from semantic-ui-react)

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm trying to use semantic UI for React with its modal.

Dropdown is ok but modal can't load :

```
import {DropDown} from "semantic-ui-react";
import {Modal} from "semantic-ui-react";

export default class Builder extends Component {  
  render(){
  return(

   <DropDown/>
   <Modal/>
)
}
}
```

The console is returning this error :

```
app.js:547 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string 
(for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined
You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. 
Check the render method of `Portal`.
```

I have already tried like this :

```
import Modal from "semantic-ui-react";
```

And as I saw, Modal folder is at the same level as the Dropdown in my packages.
Any help would be welcome!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution to your problem is either of the following:

1. You forgot to import `import React, { Component } from "react";`
2. The structure of your code. You must wrap both JSX elements in an enclosing tag as they are adjacent. It should be like this:

   `<div>
       <Dropdown/>
       <Modal/>
     </div>`
3. You don't have to separate import two components as they are both in `semantic-ui-react` library.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did all you said and updated my React to its lastest version and everything works fine now!